# how to call two JavaScript functions in onclick event on my nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a node and edge diagram. For this I have created an onclick method. When I click on a node, I want the colour of the node to change and the info from the node to be displayed in my separately created box.
The function for changing the colour is called

```
function changeColorClick (e, d)
```

And the function that gives the info is called:

```
function showDetails(e,d)
```

Now the question is how can I include both functions in one onclick? If I execute individual functions, it works. But how do I manage to execute both methods?

When I run both together, I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: node.getAttribute is not a function
    at new ClassList (d3.v6.js:1923)
    at classList (d3.v6.js:1918)
    at classedAdd (d3.v6.js:1947)
    at d3.v6.js:1958
    at Selection$1.selection_each [as each] (d3.v6.js:1781)
    at Selection$1.selection_classed [as classed] (d3.v6.js:1983)
    at onClickNode (index.html:179)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (index.html:160)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.v6.js:2107)
```

```
  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter()
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style('fill', 'red')
      .on("click", (e, d) => {
        showDetails(e, d);
        onClickNode(e, d);
      });
```

Comment: There is no issue in the code you have shared - it should work exactly as expected. *Based on previous questions, I'm presuming you have a `d3.select(this)` in a function generating the error, arrow functions have different `this` context - it isn't the node in this case. If so, one option you can try `.on("click.foo",showDetails).on("click.bar",onClickNode)` if you want to have two separate event listeners for the same event and pass the node as `this`. But without seeing what is generating the error (something within the two functions), this is only an educated guess*.

Comment: on the function `showDetails`im using `d3.select("#detail_box")...` and on `onclickNode` im using ` d3.select(this)....` and `svg.selectAll..`.

Comment: @AndrewReid - thx its working.

Comment: The duplicate questions may be useful as their answers provide a bit more clarity and info than I have in my comment - both with excellent answers by those with a better command of D3 than myself.